# Rails Paperclip how to use filter options of ImageMagick?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, imagemagick, paperclip

I recently implemented Paperclip with Rails and want to try out some of the filter options from ImageMagick such as [blur](http://www.imagemagick.org/Usage/blur/). I've not been able to find any examples of how to do this. Does it get passed through :style as another option?

```
:styles => { :medium => "300x300#", :thumb => "100x100#" }
```

---

@plang's answer was correct but I wanted to give the exact solution to the blur, just in case someone was looking and found this question:

```
:convert_options => { :all => "-blur 0x8" }
// -blur  {radius}x{sigma}
```

Which changed this:
[image]

To this:
[image]

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I did not test this, but you should be able to use the "convert_options" parameter, like this:

```
:convert_options => { :all => ‘-colorspace Gray’ }
```

Have a look at https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip/blob/master/lib/paperclip/thumbnail.rb

I personnaly use my own processor.

In Model:

```
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    :url  => PaperclipAssetsController.config_url,
                    :path => PaperclipAssetsController.config_path,
                    :styles => {
                                 :grayscale => { :processors => [:grayscale] }
                               }
```

In lib:

```
module Paperclip
  # Handles grayscale conversion of images that are uploaded.
  class Grayscale < Processor

    def initialize file, options = {}, attachment = nil
      super
      @format = File.extname(@file.path)
      @basename = File.basename(@file.path, @format)
    end

     def make  
       src = @file
       dst = Tempfile.new([@basename, @format])
       dst.binmode

       begin
         parameters = []
         parameters << ":source"
         parameters << "-colorspace Gray"
         parameters << ":dest"

         parameters = parameters.flatten.compact.join(" ").strip.squeeze(" ")

         success = Paperclip.run("convert", parameters, :source => "#{File.expand_path(src.path)}[0]", :dest => File.expand_path(dst.path))
       rescue PaperclipCommandLineError => e
         raise PaperclipError, "There was an error during the grayscale conversion for #{@basename}" if @whiny
       end

       dst
     end

  end
end
```

This might not be 100% necessary for a simple grayscale conversion, but it works!

Comment: Well feels like it is wayyy easier to add in in the convert options
`:styles => { :grey     => "450x250" }, :convert_options => {:grey     => "-blur 0x8"}`

Answer (score 0):

**Rails 5, Paperclip 5 update**

Instead of having to add a library now, you can just call out to [ImageMagick's convert command](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php) on the system to use its [grayscale option](http://www.imagemagick.org/script/command-line-options.php#grayscale).  You can do the same for blur or any of the other ImageMagick options, but I needed to do this for conversion to grayscale.

In your model (client that has a logo):

```
class Client < ApplicationRecord
  has_attached_file :logo,
                    styles: { thumb: "243x243#", grayscale: "243x243#" }
  # ensure it's an image
  validates_attachment_content_type :logo, content_type: /\Aimage\/.*\z/

  # optional, just for name and url to be required
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :url, presence: true

  after_save :convert_grayscale

  def convert_grayscale
    system "convert #{self.logo.path(:thumb)} -grayscale Rec709Luminance #{self.logo.path(:grayscale)}"
  end

  def logo_attached?
    self.logo.file?
  end
end
```

Then just use in the view like this (per [Paperclips github docs](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip#view-helpers)).

In your view:

```
<%= image_tag(client.logo.url(:grayscale), class: 'thumbnail', alt: client.name, title: client.name) %>
```

or with a link if you prefer:

```
<%= link_to(image_tag(client.logo.url(:grayscale), class: 'thumbnail', alt: client.name, title: client.name), client.url ) %>
```