# A gem to convert a picture into black and white grid

Tags: ruby, rmagick, gtk2

I have to convert a colored picture into a duotone black and white picture. I forced the edges to have good result, but the result isn't good enough.

I'm using rMagick with Ruby, but I'm looking for a better gem.

Comment: What do you mean with "I forced the edges to have good result, but the result isn't good enough." example of desired picture and what you got?

Comment: It probably a question of finding the right parameters, and not one of finding another gem.

Comment: It's about the way to get a duotone picture efficiently enough to be able to get pixel by pixel a grid of the game "nonogram", "logigram" or "picross".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Paperclip](https://github.com/thoughtbot/paperclip) is really great. You can use different processors and make with your pictures nearly everything.

Example for you is here: [Rails Paperclip how to use filter options of ImageMagick?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4435922/rails-paperclip-how-to-use-filter-options-of-imagemagick)

Comment: I'll give it a try, i'll come later to tell you. Thx for your answer.